# How to combine temperature values for three different years into one variable for time series data?

Tags: r

I have tried to look at other questions at this forum, but did not find the suitable answer for my query. That's why i am asking this question here:

I have a time series data with daily mean temperature values for 3 years 2017, 2018 and 2019 separately. For example like this:

```
           1.1.2017   1.1.2018   1.1.2019
Temperature     21          23        24
```

Now i want to make one variable that represents daily mean temperature for 2017, 18 and 19. How should i do that in R?

I am sorry if that's a very basic question but i am really stuck at it and don't know what to do? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you need a mean of 2017, 2018 and 2019 together as one variable?

Comment: Please add sample data using `dput(df)` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the expected output for your example data?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/680068

Comment: Yes i want a mean of 2017, 2018 and 2019 as one new variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

1. input is a one row data frame with Temperature being a row name as in DF shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.
2. output is to be a two column data frame with data in first column and year in second column.

Code--

```
DF2 <- transform(stack(DF), ind = as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "", ind)))
DF2
##   values  ind
## 1     21 2017
## 2     23 2018
## 3     24 2019
```

or if you want a zoo or ts series

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF2, index = 2)
as.ts(z)
## Time Series:
## Start = 2017 
## End = 2019 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1] 21 23 24
```

The code via zoo is more general since it can also handle non-consecutive years but if we knew that the years were consecutive, i.e. no missing years, then we could write this directly from DF2

```
with(DF2, ts(values, start = ind[1]))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "           1.1.2017   1.1.2018   1.1.2019
Temperature     21          23        24"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```